# Obtaining the date of a file that has been stored as an environment variable

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

My below code fails to pause so I can't see if it works:

```
@Echo
for /f  "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir C:\Users\name\Downloads\ /b /od') do set newest=%%a
for %%a in (%newest%) do set FileDate=%~ta
pause
```

The main aim is to move the most recent file (daily) from a SSRS serve to a Linux server (SFTP). I'm storing the date to be used as: If the most recent file does not equal today's date then stop command.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for the most recent of today's files? Can you please also explain what you mean by most recent file?

Comment: the files are generated at 1am every day but are all stored in the same folder; so most recent = last modified date

Comment: So you only want any file last modified today, not the newest, _(as there should only be one)_. The simplest method to understand may be the `ForFiles` command. Open a Command Prompt window and enter `forfiles /?` to read its usage information.

Comment: when it "fails to pause", it breaks before, most probably due to a syntax error. Indeed, you used `%~ta` instead of `%%~ta`. Also you took care of files with spaces in their name with `tokens=*`, so you should use `for %%a in ("%newest%")... too.

Comment: Open a command prompt window, navigate to the parent directory of the batch script (using command `cd /D`) and execute the batch script by typing its name; you will see any returned error messages then...

Comment: There is no reason to use an extra `for` loop, just do this: `for /F  "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /B /A:D "C:\Users\name\Downloads\"') do set "FileDateOfNewest=%%~ta"`...

Answer (score 2):

The following batch file code could be used to get last modification date and time of newest file according to last modification date in date/time format defined by the country configured for the used user account on execution of the batch file.

```
@echo off
for /F  "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%UserProfile%\Downloads\*" /A-D /B /O-D 2^>nul') do (
    set "NewestFileName=%UserProfile%\Downloads\%%I"
    for %%J in ("%UserProfile%\Downloads\%%I") do set "NewestFileDate=%%~tJ"
    goto FoundNewestFile
)
echo No file found in folder "%UserProfile%\Downloads".
goto :EOF

:FoundNewestFile
echo  Newest file: "%NewestFileName%"
echo Date of file: %NewestFileDate%
pause
```

**Note:** The command **DIR** outputs with the used options the file name of the newest file first **without path**. For that reason it is necessary to specify in inner **FOR** loop once again the directory path containing the newest file to get the last modification date of this file in the user's downloads folder. Otherwise the inner **FOR** would search for the newest file in current directory on execution of the batch file which is most likely not the user's downloads directory and so fails to find the file and determine its last modification date.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`

Read the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are reporting is caused by a syntax error: it should read `%%~ta` rather than `%~ta`. If you ran the batch file by opening a command prompt, navigating to its parent directory (using `cd /D`) and typing the name of the script, the window would not close afterwards, so you could see any error messages.

---

But there is another problem (as user [Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564) already pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59355991)): the `dir /B` command returns pure file names, although you specified the target directory, and the inner `for` loop refers to the current working directory, since you did not specify the target directory there.

To avoid that problem you could simply change to the target directory in advance once, then do the rest:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Change to target directory in advance:
cd /D "%UserProfile%\Downloads"
rem // Do whatever you want to do at that location:
for /F "delims= eol=|" %%a in ('dir /B /A:-D /O:D "*.*"') do set "newest=%%a"
for %%a in ("%newest%") do set "FileDate=%%~ta"
echo Found file: "%newest%" (last mod.: %FileDate%)
pause
```

You could also use `pushd`/`popd` for that:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Change to target directory in advance (quit in case of an error):
pushd "%UserProfile%\Downloads" || exit /B 1
rem // Do whatever you want to do at that location:
for /F "delims= eol=|" %%a in ('dir /B /A:-D /O:D "*.*"') do set "newest=%%a"
for %%a in ("%newest%") do set "FileDate=%%~ta"
rem // Return to original working directory:
popd
echo Found file: "%newest%" (last mod.: %FileDate%)
pause
```

The filter option `/A:-D` of `dir` avoids directories to be processed also.

---

Actually there is no need to use two nested `for` loops, one loop is sufficient:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Change to target directory in advance (of course `pushd`/`popd` could also be used):
cd /D "%UserProfile%\Downloads"
rem // Use a single loop and gather both file name and file date:
for /F "delims= eol=|" %%a in ('dir /B /A:-D /O:D "*.*"') do (
    set "newest=%%a"
    set "FileDate=%%~ta"
)
echo Found file: "%newest%" (last mod.: %FileDate%)
pause
```

---

In case there are many files the above `for /F` loop is going to iterate a lot of times until it reaches the newest file (or, to be precise, the last modified one). To avoid slow execution you could simply reverse the sort order of the files returned by `dir` (when using `/O:-D`) and leave the `for /F` loop upon the first iteration:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Change to target directory in advance (of course `pushd`/`popd` could also be used):
cd /D "%UserProfile%\Downloads"
rem // Use a single loop and gather both file name and file date:
for /F "delims= eol=|" %%a in ('dir /B /A:-D /O:-D "*.*"') do (
    set "newest=%%a"
    set "FileDate=%%~ta"
    goto :CONTINUE
)
:CONTINUE
echo Found file: "%newest%" (last mod.: %FileDate%)
pause
```